# Check for resizing of the browser window

Tags: jquery, loops

I am trying to make a loop that constantly checks the size of the site and remove an attribute when it gets smaller and add it back when it gets bigger. I been trying to get this working for a while now, and I am unable to do so.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    if(document.body.clientWidth <= 767) {
        $("div").removeAttr("attr");
    }
});
$(function() {
    if(document.body.clientWidth >= 768) {
        $("div").attr("attr", "content");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: use an event-handler and the [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) event for that (or with the use of jQuery: [.resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/))

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/resize/ check this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do the initial check of the window size and set values and then on resize set the values .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      SetWidth($(window).width());

     $(window).on('resize', function(){
          SetWidth($(this).width());
      });
}); 

function SetWidth(windowWidth) {
          if(windowWidth <= 767){
              $("div").removeAttr("attr");
           }
           else {
            $("div").attr("attr", "content");
           }
}
```